# String formatting in Python

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

How do I format the following numbers that are in vector?

For an instance, numbers which I have:

> 23.02567
>
> 0.025679

and I would like to format to this:

> 0.230256700+E02
>
> 0.025679000+E00

Comment: Why would you format as `0.230256700+E02`? Scientific notation _always_ has one digit before the decimal point, that's the entire point of that notation. (Possible exception is to restrict the `E` part to powers of `1000`, corresponding to `k`, `M`, `G`, etc.)

Comment: For "proper" scientific notation, try `"%E" % x` or `"{:E}".format(x)`, which yield `'2.302567E+01'`. Note the number of digits before the decimal point and the position of the `+`.

Comment: Sadly, that's not my decision. The asked format is the input to another program. I agree, this not common formatting. It was surprising for me too.

Comment: So, how do you decide on the exponent? Is that another parameter? Why do those example has E02 and E00 respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that this is *not* the proper way to format numbers in scientific- or engineering-notation. Those numbers should always have exactly one digit in front of the decimal point, unless the exponent is required to be a multiple of 3 (i.e. a power of 1000, corresponding to one of the SI prefixes). If, however, you *have* to use this format, you could write your own format string for that.

```
>>> x, e = 23.02567, 2
>>> "%f%sE%02d" % (x/10**e, "+" if e >= 0 else "-", abs(e))
'0.230257+E02'
>>> x, e = 0.025679, -1
>>> "%f%sE%02d" % (x/10**e, "+" if e >= 0 else "-", abs(e))
'0.256790-E01'
```

This is assuming that the exponent, `e`, is given. If the exponent does not matter, you could also use the proper `%E` format and just `replace` `E+` with `+E`:

```
>>> ("%E" % x).replace("E+", "+E").replace("E-", "-E")
'2.567900-E02'
```

Comment: Dear Tobias, thank you for your kind answer. I am gratefull.